# Escaping quotes in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I am building a json object in jinja file:

```
object_name = {
    property_name: "{{ _("Some Text which might have "quotes" in it")  }}"
}
```

And then import the above jinja2 file in a script tag

note: _("Text") is used to be replaced by a translation text, so the text in the () will be replaced with text of another language so i can not predict if the translation will contain double quotes

any idea how to escape the incoming quotes and convert them to for example "

**Edited**

**The solution:**

The solution to this problem for us was by making python go through all the translations and escape all qoutations. but we always have to make sure at least the english text not to be problematic and anyway we have controll over this.... so far :)

**Look at this document aswell**

http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html#sec-poescapes

Answer (score 18):

Jinja2 starting from version 2.9 has nice filter [tojson](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson). If you make json from string, it will generate string enclosed in double quotes "". You can safely use it in javascript. And you don't need put quotes around by yourself.

```
string = {{ html_string|tojson }};
```

In your particular case it might be easier to create dict in Python and then convert it to javascript object with single use of

```
jsObject = {{ py_dict|tojson }};
```

`tojson` escapes quotes `"` and also prevents XSS by escaping important symbols like `<>&'`. Tested at on jinja 2.10:

```
t = jinja2.Template('{{s|tojson}}')
r = t.render(s="""</script>"...'""")
print(r) # "\u003c/script\u003e\"...\u0027"
```

Comment: Re "You can safely use it in javascript" - be careful, this is not really true. If the input string contains `</script>`, this will be interpreted by the browsers as ending HTML tag, even if it is inside the quoted string! Add another `<script>` after it, and you have a nice XSS. I don't have a good solution except replacing `</script>` though.

Comment: My current jinja2 (2.10) renders it as `"\\u003c/script\\u003e"`. It is safe

Answer (score 10):

In `flask`, there is a default filter called `tojson` that you could use or, with plain `jinja2`, you can create your own `tojson` filter:

```
>>> import json
>>> env = jinja2.Environment()
>>> env.filters['tojson'] = json.dumps
>>> tmpl = env.from_string("""\
object_name = {
    property_name: {{ _(text)|tojson  }}
}""")
>>> print tmpl.render({'_': lambda x: x, 'text': 'Some text with "Quotes"'})
object_name = {
    property_name: "Some text with \"Quotes\""
}
```

Comment: `tojson` is great. Had a list of objects, which I needed as json array.  `tags | map(attribute='title') | list | tojson`

Answer (score 4):

didn't understand the question clearly. if escaping with single backslashes didn't work, escape backslashes as well using

```
object_name = {
    property_name: "{{ _(\\\"Some Text which might have \\\"quotes\\\" in it\\\")  }}"
}
```

Comment: Yes escaping with backslash works but the English text will automatically get replaced with for example french text and we never know if that french text has " in it

Answer (score 3):

Filters are applied [sequentially](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#filters) so you can do something like this assuming you have your text in the variable `sometext`:

```
{{sometext|replace('"',"'")|safe}}
```

This will apply a `replace` before marking the string as safe. Remember that you have to trust the source of the string to avoid vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to escape HTML in javascript, jinja2 also has the [escape](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#escape) filter. This translates &, <, >, ‘, and ” to entities so you can edit html code in a prompt, for instance.